# How to merge two numbers and store it in another with point in between them

Tags: c, merge, numbers

I am making a C program in which I have two numbers `num1=11` and `num2=98` . I want them to store it in another number like `num3=11.98` That point between 11 and 98 is important. How to do this. Please help, thanks.!

Comment: `char rez[100]; snprintf(rez, sizeof rez, "%d.%d", num1, num2); num3 = strtod(rez, NULL);`

Comment: `float num3 = strtof(num1 + "." + num2);`

Comment: What if `num2 = 3`? or `num2 = 1704821`?

Comment: Here's the general idea (I don't do C, so you'll need to translate) `(num1+(num2/pow(10,ceil(log10(num2)))))`

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman it is saying two few argument to statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code like below might solve your problem.

```
float floatingNum = num2;
while(floatingNum > 1)
{
  floatingNum = floatingNum / 10;
}
float num3 = num1 + floatingNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming num1 and num2 are already declared and assigned values)

Find length of num2 and store it in variable "len2"

```
float num3 = (float)num1 + ((float)num2 / pow(10,len2));
```